# Prevent HTML elements from overlapping each other on smaller screens

Tags: html, css

I have two elements on a page that are aligned side by side to each other. The element on the left is fixed. My default screen resolution is 1280x800. As the screen resolution decreases to 1024x* or less, the left and right containers tend to overlap each other. Is there a fix to this problem? How do I do it?
-----------------------------------------------------------Edit-----------------------------------------------------------
Actually, the element to the right is assigned a pre-defined width and is set to `margin:0 auto` to keep it oriented to the center of the screen. The element to the <s>right</s> left is a vertical menu, and hence, I want it to stay fixed even when the user scrolls the page. Hence I've specified `position:fixed` for it.

Comment: And the element on the right?

Comment: @Sime Vidas I've edited the post to detail the issue. Please consider.

Comment: @zzzzBov I tried applying min-width to body, but then, as I scrolled horizontally, the fixed element overlapped the other.

Comment: @ikartik What do you want to happen when the user resizes the window to a small width?

Comment: @Sime Vidas All I want is that the elements do not overlap each other, their functionalities remaining the same,i.e., left element position:fixed and right element margin:0 auto.

Comment: @ikartik That is not possible. If the centered element has a set width and the browser window is smaller than that width, then that element will take up all horizontal space and there won't be any space left for the menu on the left ... You do understand that, right?

Comment: @Sime Vidas That's well understood, but in case of the screen resolution being 1024x* there is enough space on the left for the icons to place themselves. the width of the right element is set to 765px.

Comment: @ikartik If the width of the centered element is 765px, on a 1024px wide resolution, you will have around 120px free space on the left. If the menu on the left is wider than 120px, it will overlap.

Comment: @Sime Vidas It's just 50px wide.

Comment: @ikartik Overlapping should not happen as long as the page width is 870px or higher. See here: http://vidasp.net/tinydemos/overlapping2.html

Comment: @ikartik - why don't you post sample HTML/CSS that shows exactly what problem you are having? What you are describing should not happen, as @Šime Vidas has said.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do this client side, shrinking the containers appropriately in a window.onresize event handler.

Answer (score 0):

If they're colliding because the screen isn't big enough to hold both of them, try setting the width of the elements to a percentage: `<tag style="width: 80%;" />`.